# Loading multiple templates in Twig

Tags: php, twig

I am fiddling with Twig and I like it so far. I do have a problem though, I want to load 2 or more templates from the PHP site and " merge " them together in 1 render or multiple if that gives the same result.

Lets say I have a class that has to do the rendering and I have these templates, template layout.tmpl in /site/templates/layouts/layout.tmpl:

```
{% block head %}
<head>
blabla
</head>
{% endblock %}
```

And a template called view.tmpl in /site/templates/Home/view.tmpl

```
{% block head %}
<head>
blabla2
</head>
{% endblock %}
```

What PHP code do I require and what is smart. So I dont want to use the {% extends %} in the template file itself?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

you can include that file. Like:

```
    {% include 'header.html' %}
    Body
    {% include 'footer.html' %}
```

Comment: I know but I don't really want to use the templates for that, I want to bind them together via the PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround far from pretty but it gets the job done.

```
$template_contents = file_get_contents();
$layout_contents = file_get_contents();
$template_contents = "{% extends \"layout.tmpl\" %}" . $template_contents; 

$loader = Twig_Loader_Array(array('layout.tmpl' => $layout_contents, 'template.tmpl' => $template_contents);
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->render('template.tmpl');
```